# How to display Unicode &#xf003; in Coldfusion in a CSS button

Tags: css, button, unicode, coldfusion

There maybe a simple answer but I can't seem to find the answer specifically for Coldfusion.  I am having trouble displaying Unicode that displays symbols such as `&#xf003;` which shows an icon of an envelope.  Many of these symbols are shown [here](http://www.aeriinfotech.com/docs/FA_ICONS/design.html)

I want to display the envelope and then the word "Contact Me".  However, Coldfusion is complaining about the semi-colon ";".   The html is encoded in UTF-8.

Your assistance is much appreciated.  Thank you.

EDITED: 
I have also loaded the font with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But still not working.  I test out

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
```

It displays the envelope properly, so I know I have loaded the fonts.

I am basically trying to put an icon/gif of an envelope in a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Contact Me">
```

I have tried

```
<input type="submit" class="button blue" value="&##xf003; Contact Me">
```

which simply displayed a square box before the Contact Me.  This code displays a blue button with the word "Contact Me". Like [this](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-buttons.html).  I want the icon/gif before the word.  I thought I could do it with the `&#xf003;` code.  If I can't maybe someone can show me how to put a gif inside the css button?  Not sure if I shall add this as a new question?

Comment: are you in a `cfoutput` block? you will need to escape the `#` if you are. eg  `&##xf003;`

Comment: It looks like you are using a Font-Awesome character. You have to make sure the Font-Awesome font [sic] is in use when you display it

Comment: It's easy to tell what's going on here, but as a rule of thumb, always include the exact error message and the code producing it in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs ("[Special characters](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Special+characters)"):

> The double-quotation marks ("), single-quotation mark ('), and number sign (#) characters have special meaning to ColdFusion. To include any of them in a string, double the character; for example, use ## to represent a single # character.

Comment: When I used the ## in '&##xf003;' it is not giving error, however, it is showing a square box and not the envelope symbol.

Comment: Sounds like it's - as @james-a-mohler suggested: you don't actually have the requisite font installed correctly / at all.

Comment: I have added the font, but still having the same issue :(

Comment: I can only suggest you do a bit of research into how to make these things work. However it's nothing to do with this question, as if you wanted to express `&#xf003;` within CFML code, and now you know how. That doing that doesn't result in what you want is another issue (one I know nothing about). So... do some research, do some troubleshooting, and perhaps ask another question.